# tfs build not copying to drop location when using intermediate build project

Tags: msbuild, nuget

I am updating my TFS build definition to use nuget restore according to [this documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/team-foundation-build).  My solution builds successfully, but no build output is copied to the drop location.  I'm not sure how to determine why.  In the MS Build log I see my output being created in the binaries directory, for example:

```
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
    Copying file from "obj\Release\ConsoleApp1.exe" to "C:\Builds\4\TestBuild\Binaries\ConsoleApp1.exe".
```

This is also the same location I see being specified in the Copy Files to Drop Location step of the TFS build log.  What am I missing?  I am using on premise TFS Version 15.105.25910.0.  Is there another way to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the build template being used by the build definition.  The 'Copy to Drop Location' was heavily customized and reading the contents of the ListOfAssembly.txt file to determine copy contents.  I changed it a step from another stock template that worked correctly:

```
<mtbwa:CopyDirectory Destination="[BuildDetail.DropLocation]" DisplayName="Copy Files to Drop Location" Source="[BinariesDirectory]" />
```

And got the output expected.